# Is there a way to set project level configuration in WebStorm?

Tags: node.js, npm, config, webstorm

I am working on a ReactJS enterprise project that has its own url for npm registry.

While installing native CSS Animation addons in the project using `npm install` I was informed that such package is currently unavailable in the global registry.

I have set the registry **globally** using the `npm config set registry <url> --globally` command, but don't want this change to affect my other Node.js projects.

Is there a way to set the registry for the said project through WebStorm? 
So that it doesn't interfere with other stand-one projects?

And setting registry is just an example. The question intends to find a way to override all global configurations for a particular project, be it npm configs or node version configs.

Comment: `.npmrc` files? https://docs.npmjs.com/files/npmrc  Do not see what WebStorm has to do here .. since you will be executing all commands via `npm` directly in terminal. If you do not want any other projects to see that custom registry .. then why it was set globally in first place?

Comment: Got a fairly good video for setting project level node settings.
Check out the link: https://youtu.be/xuXIBSa_7j4?t=906

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about npm url but moost of other settings can be configured on  **Project level**[image: project level]basis by taking settings from file menu:

**File->Settings**

For **global settings** you can alter default settings like:

File->Default settings

**[image: File->Default settings].**

Using the above method you can configure different project to use different Node and Npm versions. Simply download Node tarball and extract it to local dir and point to it in Project level settings in Webstorm.